# How to introduce user in database and images in storage in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a social media app and I use firebase to add database . I followed a tutorial and it doesn't appear users in database and neither the photo profile in storage . I think that I didn't introduce database right in signup controller [databasephoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8az7W.png)
 [storagephoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOwCt.png) I also can post the home view controller code

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var tapToChangeProfileButton: UIButton!


var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController!

@IBAction func ContinueButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if emailTextField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error",message: "Please enert your emiail and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("You have successfully signed up")
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                self.present(alertController,animated: true, completion:  nil)
            }
        }
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self


    let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
    profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
    profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.bounds.height / 2
    profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    //tapToChangeProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.delegate = self



}
@objc func openImagePicker(_ sender:Any) {
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:  nil)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    usernameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


@objc func handleSignUp() {
    guard let username = usernameTextField.text else { return }
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    guard let image = profileImageView.image else { return }


    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            print("User created!")

            self.uploadProfileImage(image) { url in

                if url != nil {



                    let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest?.displayName = username
                    changeRequest?.photoURL = url

                    changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in
                        if error == nil {
                            print("User display name changed!")
                            self.saveProfile(username: username, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                if success {
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    //error unable to upload profile image
                }

            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("user/\(uid)")

    guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
        if error == nil, metaData != nil {

            storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in


                completion(url)
                // success!
            }
        } else {
            // failed
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}


func saveProfile(username:String, profileImageURL:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ success:Bool)->())) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")

    let userObject = [
        "username": username,
        "photoURL": profileImageURL.absoluteString
        ] as [String:Any]

    databaseRef.setValue(userObject) { error, ref in
        completion(error == nil)
    }
}
}





extension SignUpViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.profileImageView.image = pickedImage

        }


        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }








}
```

```css
//this is in my post viewcontroller

import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol NewPostVCDelegate {
    func didUploadPost(withID id:String)
}
class NewPostViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?


@IBAction func handlePostButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //   https://clout2-39505.firebaseio.com/
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
    print(user)

    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let postObject = [
        "author": [

            "uid": user.providerID,
            "username": user.email,
            "photoURL": "path"
        ],
        "text": textView.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"]


        ] as [String:Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: {error, ref in
        if error == nil{
            self.delegate?.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            //Handle the error
        }
    })
}



@IBAction func handleCancelButton(_ sender: Any){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)


    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()

    // Remove the nav shadow underline
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: What's your question? I highly recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as they make it much more likely that someone will (be able to) help.

Comment: We need a bit more to go on as well. You've got a bunch of print statements in your code, which is great for troubkeshooting. Which one isn't printing? If you put in a breakpoint and step through your code - which part isn't populating the variables correctly?

Comment: I think the problem it's at 
    let postObject = [
        "author": [

            "uid": user.providerID,
            "username": user.email,
            "photoURL": "path"
        ],
        "text": textView.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv":"timestamp"] ----- I don't know what to put instead of user.email